# Check if a link already exists on a page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to solve for two scenarios:

1. Identify if the link clicked exists already on the page.
2. Then if the link already exists, get the index() for the link clicked of the duplicate links.

My code is not working correctly since it's not identifying correctly if the link clicked is a duplicate and it's giving me an index of the sum of all links instead of the duplicate link.

```
$("a").click(function() {
   Rank = $(this).index('a');
   if($("a").attr("href") != $(this).attr("href")) {
        alert('\nLink Rank '+Rank+'\n\nYes, this is duplicate link');
       return false;
    }
    else {
        alert('\nLink Rank '+Rank+'\n\nNo, this is NOT a duplicate link');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/no4gkk0n/1/

Comment: `$("a").attr("href")` takes `href` of first `<a>` on the page.

Comment: You could probably query all links with that href by using `$("a[href='"+$(this).attr("href")+"']").each(function(item) {} );`

Comment: How could a clicked link not already exist? Did Descartes not say, *"clickio ergo sum"*? Something like that anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look for elements with the same attribute with the attribute selector: `[href="foo"]`, then check the `length` property. If it's more than 1, there is a duplicate link:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Rank = $(this).index('a');
    if ($("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").length > 1) {
        alert('\nLink Rank ' + Rank + '\n\nYes, this is duplicate link');
    } else {
        alert('\nLink Rank ' + Rank + '\n\nNo, this is NOT a duplicate link');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/no4gkk0n/2/)

Comment: Thanks. That solves for scenario 1. The rank still shows 1-7 in order. The last challenge I wasn't able to solve is to identify the index of the duplicate link.

Comment: Example link at the top, wouldn't that be a "1" rank and then the Examples at the bottom would be a "2" and a "3" respectively if reading from top to bottom, yea? It seems I'm shown a "5" then a "1" and then another "1", yea?

Comment: The first 'Examples' is a 5 because that's the index of the next 'Examples' link. The Examples at the bottom shows 1 because index is zero based.

Comment: I see, however, in this http://jsfiddle.net/no4gkk0n/4/ can't I have it like this: Example at the top flagged as 0, the next Example should be 1 and the final Example should be 2. Something like that? Then Google would be 0, Amazon would be 0, the next Amazon would be 1.